# Filter flickr images

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm developing an iPhone app where I need to have some images. Particulary I have to retrive some images from internet and then show them in a specific cell.

For example: tapping the cell numb. 1 i have to show some images about an object A, tapping the cell numb. 2 about an object B and so on.

Do you think the best web site to store the images is Flickr?
Do you think it is possibile "matching" a Flickr tag to an iPhone request?
What could be the best solution for my needs?

Thank a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'iPhone' app will be composing the 'request' based on a web server's published API.  The [Flick API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/) looks workable for this.  And, here is an [Objective-C Framework for the Flickr API](https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr).

Comment: So... it's possible! Thank you!